# YII2: I am getting 500 error while i logged out from backend

Tags: yii2, backend, http-status-code-500

```
mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500
```

This error i am getting after i logged out from backend. 
It is working fine on my localhost but problem is coming when site is live. 
What are the reasons of this kind of error.And there are no entries in my server error logs. I don't know what is wrong.
Please help thank you in advance.

Comment: This information is not enough to give you answer. did you change the index file of your application?

Comment: No, i didn't change index file. What information you need ?

Comment: I want to know, have you changed anything while making your application live?

Comment: Many peoples are working in this project the problem is coming from last  six 6 months. I don't know what changes they have made before making site live. Whole site is working fine but when user logged out it gives this error. So now do you have idea what are the causes of this kind of error. Really i got stuck from last 6-7 days.

Comment: try debugging, I cant guess it directly.

Comment: It is not sufficient information to answer your question at the moment.

Comment: Post your server log files and/or Yii's app.log content for a start

Comment: There is no entries in server error logs...

Comment: in app.log there is an entry " syntax error or access violation: 1142 DELETE command denied to user 'ramkisan'@'localhost' for table 'session'
The SQL being executed was: DELETE FROM `session` WHERE `id`='dvk6fjfq3 "

Comment: I think i need to uncheck delete privilege in my database ... am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2, logout must be `POST`, your link to logout can't be `GET`.